# how can I visualize the bag-of-words in a scatterplot

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-mining, bigdata, visualization

I have a bag-of-words consisting of about 60000 features. Each feature represents a diminsion. I want to represent this bag-of-words in a reduced 2D space. How do I do it?

I have see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28160335/plot-a-document-tfidf-2d-graph), which looks more like what I want but not really the same. In the example they have 2 transform and I only have one. Therefore as suggested I do not want to use pipeline. Below is my code which taking for ever and does not show any error message:

```
#myList contents about 800000 words
bag_of_words = vec.fit_transform(myList)
X = bag_of_words.todense()
pca = PCA(n_components=2).fit(X)
data2D = pca.transform(X)
plt.scatter(data2D[:,0], data2D[:,1])
plt.show()
```

I have not found any better option and right now it looks like I am doing something wrong.

What is the best way to visualize a bag-of-words in a scatterplot?

The bag_of_words looks like this:

```
(0, 548)    3
(0, 4000)   6
(0, 15346)  1
(0, 23299)  1
(0, 22931)  2
(0, 32817)  1
(0, 51733)  1
(0, 38308)  6
(0, 14784)  1
(0, 146873) 1
 ....
```

Comment: Is the PCA visualization not good enough for you?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should have a look at t-SNE which is a visualization technique based on dimensionality reduction. [Wikipedia excerpt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-distributed_stochastic_neighbor_embedding#cite_note-1):

> t-distributed stochastic neighbor embedding (t-SNE) is a machine learning algorithm for dimensionality reduction developed by Geoffrey Hinton and Laurens van der Maaten. It is a nonlinear dimensionality reduction technique that is particularly well-suited for embedding high-dimensional data into a space of two or three dimensions, which can then be visualized in a scatter plot. Specifically, it models each high-dimensional object by a two- or three-dimensional point in such a way that similar objects are modeled by nearby points and dissimilar objects are modeled by distant points.

[image]

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.00534.pdf) describes a python implementation of the technique on various word2vec datasets.